# What is the use case of having static members inside a Method local inner class in Java?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I was completely blown away after I made a static member in Method local inner class, I am wondering what might be its use case as the scope of MLIC member is only inside the method in which they are defined.
Are MLIC's implicitly static? Then how am I able to access instance members from outer class?

```
class Test {
    int i = 8;

        //instance method
    void m() {
                //method local inner class  
        class I1{    
            static int x2 = 2; //static variable declaration

            public void main() {   
                System.out.println(i);  //outer class instance variable accessible
            }
            
            static void print() { //static method declaration
                System.out.println("I am a static method in MLIC");
            }
        }
        
        I1 i1 = new I1();
        i1.main();
        
        I1.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: A local class is an inner class, so no, they are not implicitly static. Adding static members to local classes became possible in Java 16 as part of [JEP 395: Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395): "*Relax the longstanding restriction whereby an inner class cannot declare a member that is explicitly or implicitly static. This will become legal and, in particular, will allow an inner class to declare a member that is a record class*".

Comment: As for why you'd want to add a static field or method to a local class, I don't know a real use case off the top of my head. Though a static field will obviously be associated with the class and thus be shared between all instances of the class, just like normal. There might be a reason to make use of that. But static _methods_ in a local class seem less practical.